# Draw Circle or Scatterplot Layer with Haversine Curvature

Tags: geometry, geojson, haversine, turfjs, deck.gl

I've drawn a circle using Deck.gl's Scatterplot layer, but it doesn't line up with the lines I've drawn using turf.js's [destination](https://turfjs.org/docs/#destination) function. The issue is shown in this image here:

I believe the line lengths are more accurate, because they grow longer as you approach the poles. I'd like the circle to have the same warped effect. Is it possible to achieve this with turf.js and deck.gl? What might that look like?

Additionally, I have tried drawing the circle as many Deck.gl LineLayers/PathLayers segments created from the turf circles coordinates, but that did not either give the effect I was looking for.